# Relating ID's in relational table

Tags: sql, perl, foreign-keys, relational-database, dbi

I have these two insertion queries in Perl using the `DBI` module and `DBD:mysql`.

This one inserts fields `url`, `html_extr_text`, `concord_file`, and `sys_time` into table `article`:

```
my @fields = (qw(url html_extr_text concord_file sys_time));
my $fieldlist = join ", ", @fields;
my $field_placeholders = join ", ", map {'?'} @fields;

my $insert_query = qq{
    INSERT INTO article ($fieldlist)
    VALUES ($field_placeholders)
};
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($insert_query);

my $id_article;
my @id_articles;
foreach my $article_index (0 .. @output_concord_files_prepare) {
    $field_placeholders = $sth->execute(
            $url_prepare[$article_index],
            $html_pages_files_extended[$article_index],
            $output_concord_files_prepare[$article_index],
            $sys_time_prepare[$article_index]);
    $id_article = $dbh->last_insert_id(undef, undef, 'article', 'id_article');
    push @id_articles, $id_article;
    if ($field_placeholders != 1) {
        die "Error inserting records, only [$field_placeholders] got inserted: " . $sth->insert->errstr;
    }
}
print "@id_articles\n";
```

And this one inserts field `event` into table `event`:

```
@fields = (qw(event));
$fieldlist = join ", ", @fields;
$field_placeholders = join ", ", map {'?'} @fields;

$insert_query = qq{
    INSERT INTO event ($fieldlist)
    VALUES ($field_placeholders)
};
$sth = $dbh->prepare($insert_query);

my $id_event;
my @id_events;
foreach my $event_index (0 .. @event_prepare){
    $field_placeholders = $sth->execute($event_prepare[$event_index]);
    $id_event = $dbh->last_insert_id(undef, undef, 'event', 'id_event');
    push @id_events, $id_event;
    if ($field_placeholders != 1){
        die "Error inserting records, only [$field_placeholders] got inserted: " . $sth->insert->errstr;
    }
}
print "@id_events\n";
```

I'd like to create a third one-to-many relationship table. Because, one article contains multiple events, so I have this file :

```
output_concord/concord.0.txt -> earthquake
output_concord/concord.0.txt -> avalanche
output_concord/concord.0.txt -> snowfall
output_concord/concord.1.txt -> avalanche
output_concord/concord.1.txt -> rock fall
output_concord/concord.1.txt -> mud slide
output_concord/concord.4.txt -> avalanche
output_concord/concord.4.txt -> rochfall
output_concord/concord.4.txt -> topple
...
```

As you can see, I collect the IDs of each entry using the `LAST_INSERT_ID`. However I don't really know how to make the next step.

Using this file, how can I insert into a third table 'article_event_index' the ids of the two previous tables.

It would be something like this:

```
$create_query = qq{
    create table article_event_index(
        id_article int(10) NOT NULL,
        id_event int(10) NOT NULL,
        primary key (id_article, id_event),
        foreign key (id_article) references article (id_article),
        foreign key (id_event) references event (id_event)
    )
};
$dbh->do($create_query);
```

Which will contain relationships following the pattern

```
1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-4, 3-5 ...
```

I'm a newbie to Perl and databases so it's hard to formulate what I want to do. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: I assume you mean that your text file contains the values in the `concord_file` field of the `article` table, and the related value of the `event` field of the `event` table?

Comment: Exactly, and I'm searching by using it as a pattern to insert the id's in the 'article_event_index' if this is even possible

Comment: Note that, by iterating over `0 .. @output_concord_files_prepare` you are indexing one more element than the array contains. It should look like `0 .. $#output_concord_files_prepare`. The same applies to `@event_prepare`.

Comment: Unmarked cross-posts of http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1022802 and http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1023134. I wonder what you don't like about my [DBIC answer](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1022813) now, you were so enthusiastic 4 days ago.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Perl and MySQL and 4 days ago your post seemed to be the good answer for me. But unfortunately I realized that I don't understand and I don't really know how to do it, so I tried and searched something else

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you need (untested, but it does compile).

It starts by building Perl hashes to relate concord files to article IDs and events to event IDs. Then the file is read, and a pair of IDs is inserted into the new table for each relationship that can be found in the exisiting tables.

Note that the hashes are there only to avoid a long sequence of

```
SELECT id_article FROM article WHERE concord_file = ?
```

and

```
SELECT id_event FROM event WHERE event = ?
```

statements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

use constant RELATIONSHIP_FILE => 'relationships.txt';

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database', 'user', 'pass')
        or die $DBI::errstr;

$dbh->do('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_event_index');

$dbh->do(<< 'END_SQL');
CREATE TABLE article_event_index (
    id_article INT(10) NOT NULL,
    id_event INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_article, id_event),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_article) REFERENCES article (id_article),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_event) REFERENCES event (id_event)
)
END_SQL

my $articles = $dbh->selectall_hashref(
    'SELECT id_article, concord_file FROM article',
    'concord_file'
);
my $events = $dbh->selectall_hashref(
    'SELECT id_event, event FROM event',
    'event'
);

open my $fh, '<', RELATIONSHIP_FILE
        or die sprintf qq{Unable to open "%s": %s}, RELATIONSHIP_FILE, $!;

my $insert_sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO article_event_index (id_article, id_event) VALUES (?, ?)');

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($concord_file, $event) = split /\s*->\s*/;
  next unless defined $event;

  unless (exists $articles->{$concord_file}) {
    warn qq{No article record for concord file "$concord_file"};
    next;
  }
  my $id_article = $articles->{$concord_file}{id_article};

  unless (exists $events->{$event}) {
    warn qq{No event record for event "$event"};
    next;
  }
  my $id_event = $events->{$event}{id_event};

  $insert_sth->execute($id_article, $id_event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The logic seems to be there, but I still get an error message which looks like this : `code` No article record for concord file "earthquake" at db2.pl line 312, <$fh2> line 1.
No article record for concord file "avalanche" at db2.pl line 312, <$fh2> line 2.
No article record for concord file "topple" at db2.pl line 312, <$fh2> line 3.
No article record for concord file "snowfall" at db2.pl line 312, <$fh2> line 4. And so on...

Comment: Then your relationship file isn't as you showed it in your question.

Comment: The only difference is that sometimes between '->' and 'the event' you get two spaces instead of one : "-> avalanche" or "->  avalanche". Is this a problem ? Note that sometimes I have compound words like "rock fall" or even strings "the rock fall". But mainly, it's exactly the same as in the question and it contains 132 lines.

Comment: Something happens when declaring $id_event : "Use of uninitialized value $id_event in concatenation (.) or string at db2.pl line 312, <$fh2> line 132." = for each line of RELATIONSHIP_FILE. $id_article contains the right ids. The split works for both ($concord_file, $event). I checked also the output table 'article' and 'event', both of them have the right ids.

Comment: @user2007958: I apologise. I made an error in fetching the `$id_event, using the `$articles` hash instead of the `$events` hash. It's fixed, but that bug wouldn't produce the errors you describe in your first comment above - it would just fail to find the correct value for `$id_event`. You say the split works, so the file is correct: the number of spaces either side of `->` is immaterial. Please try the code as it stands now and let me know what values are being found for the two IDs that are entered into the file.

Comment: Now for $id_article I get the right list of ids. However when I print $id_event I get this error : "Use of uninitialized value $id_event in concatenation (.) or string at db2.pl line 316, <$fh2> line 106.

132
131
132
132
132
132
". The number "132" vary following the RELATIONSHIP_FILE pattern. And finally by inserting the last line which is "$insert_sth->($id_article, $id_event);" I get : "1
Not a CODE reference at db2.pl line 317, <$fh2> line 1."

Comment: I have fixed another bug in the last line of the loop. Which is line 316? I don't understand `132 131 132 132 132 132` is that data from the text file?

Comment: Ah I understand! You have a malformed last line (line 132) in your text file. Probably it is blank. I'll make another change to ignore invalid lines.

Comment: I apologize for answering so late, I didn't had access to this computer during the weekend. I made all the changes. I've checked the file, It doesn't seem to have any malformed last line. Now I get : "No article record for concord file "output_concord/concord.0.txt" at db2.pl line 305, <$fh2> line 1.
No article record for concord file "output_concord/concord.0.txt" at db2.pl line 305, <$fh2> line 2." and so on until line 132. I don't really know how to interpret this error message actually. Thanks.

Comment: After removing the 'warn' statements for $articles and $events I get this MySQL error : "DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Column 'id_event' cannot be null at db2.pl line 310, <$fh2> line 100.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '14-132' for key 'PRIMARY' at db2.pl line 310, <$fh2> line 101.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '14-132' for key 'PRIMARY' at db2.pl line 310, <$fh2> line 103.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '15-132' for key 'PRIMARY' at db2.pl line 310, <$fh2> line 105.", for each line of the RELATIONSHIP_FILE

Comment: The program is looking for rows in the `article` table that have a value for `concord_file` equal to `output_concord/concord.0.txt` etc. It's not finding a matching row so it prints a warning and proceeds to the next line of input.

Comment: At one point you said that it was producing the correct values for `$id_article`. I suggest you copy and paste my code again as it seems we have gone backwards. Don't remove the `warn` / `next` lines as they are rejecting invalid data and continuing to process it will just raise more, irrelevant errors.

Comment: Now the code is exactly as yours, this is is the message : "DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '1-5' for key 'PRIMARY' at db2.pl line 318, <$fh2> line 4. DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '1-5' for key 'PRIMARY' at db2.pl line 318,  <$fh2> line 5.
No event record for event "rockfall" at db2.pl line 313, <$fh2> line 8.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '5-20' for key 'PRIMARY' at db2.pl line 318, <$fh2> line 20. And so on... I cant put all the error message in the comment box, but it's the same until line 132

Comment: Well that sounds OK. it is telling you that lines 4 and 5 of the relationships file correspond to the same article ID + event ID (1-5). This is a primary key for the table and so must be unique. There is also no entry in your `event` table that matches `rockfall`. These are all valid error messages.

Comment: The table is filled, but with only 42 entries. The thing is that I need all the 132 relations as in the RELATIONSHIP_FILE.

Comment: You are left with a problem with your data. If you want me to help further then I need to see at least the relationships file and the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your `article` and `event` tables. Post these on line (maybe [`pastebin`](http://pastebin.com)?) and continue in private chat.

Comment: I only have a 14 reputation so I can't go on the chat. Thank you anyway, I think I'm going to ask my computer science teacher.